# Possible bug with hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So in summary, I'm trying to modify a script so that when I click an object, a ray hits the object, looks for a component in the children and makes it useable so that it can be referenced later if that makes sense. I can elaborate further so don't be afraid to comment.

I've tried researching this issue and I've found nothing that can help me in this situation. I've also seen other posts mentioning that it could be a possible bug. I'm not sure if it really is a bug or if I'm just doing something wrong.

Everything works fine except for:

```
Fighting other = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Fighting>();

Debug.Log("Other:" + other); <- This line of code gives me this in Unity:
```

> Other:Detection (Fighting)
>   UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
>   TankController:SetTargetPosition() (at 
>   Assets/Games/Chisana/Scripts/TankController.cs:63)
>   TankController:Update() (at Assets/Games/Chisana/Scripts/TankController.cs:27)

The error I'm given in Unity is:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   TankController.SetTargetPosition () (at Assets/Games/Chisana/Scripts/TankController.cs:65)
>   TankController.Update () (at Assets/Games/Chisana/Scripts/TankController.cs:27)

All of the code is as follows:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TankController : MonoBehaviour
{

Vector3 targetPosition;
Vector3 lookAtTarget;
Quaternion playerRot;
float rotSpeed = 2;
float speed = 3;
bool moving = false;
public bool selected = false;

// Use this for initialization
//void Start()
//{

//}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        SetTargetPosition();
    }
    if (moving)
        Move();
}

void SetTargetPosition()
{

    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 1000))
        {

            if (hit.collider.CompareTag("Hittable") == true && selected == true)
            {
                Debug.Log("Found Ground");
                targetPosition = hit.point;
                lookAtTarget = new Vector3(targetPosition.x - transform.position.x,
                transform.position.y,
                targetPosition.z - transform.position.z);
                playerRot = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookAtTarget);
                moving = true;
            }

            if (hit.collider.CompareTag("Unit") == true)
            {

                Debug.Log("Found Unit");

                Fighting self = GetComponent<Fighting>();

                Fighting other = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Fighting>();

                Debug.Log("Other:" + other);

                if (self.Team == other.Team)
                {
                    if (selected == false)
                    {
                        selected = true;
                        Debug.Log("Selected");
                    }
                    if (selected == true)
                    {
                        selected = false;
                        Debug.Log("Deselected");
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

void Move()
{
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation,
                                            playerRot,
                                            rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,
                                            targetPosition,
                                            speed * Time.deltaTime);

    if (transform.position == targetPosition)
        moving = false;
}
}
```

The result of this code should be that when I click an object it should select that object and then if I click it again then it should be deselected. While selected it should go to where I click and not do anything while deselected.

Instead, when I click on an object the error pops up in the console and the object does not get selected and therefore does not move.

Comment: im quite sure its no bug with unity :D are you sure either self or other `.Team` isnt null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The thing that is null is not the thing you're debug.logging:

```
Fighting self = GetComponent<Fighting>(); //this one is null
Fighting other = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Fighting>(); //this one isn't
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. My issue is fixed. It would've been helpful if unity marked that line as the problem instead.

Comment: @ToxicCookie It did. Your debug is on line 63. *`Other:Detection (Fighting) - UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object) (at TankController.cs:63)`* and the error is on line 65. *`NullReferenceException: (at TankController.cs:65) `*. As line 65 is `if (self.Team == other.Team)` and based on the information from line 63, we know that `other` can't be null. The only other thing that can throw a NPE here is `self`.